# Error while passing value to subreport in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am trying to pass a long value to a subreport. It throws the following error.

```java
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unknown subreport source class  
java.lang.Long
```

Comment: What is the variable type in the subreport?

Comment: Fixed. I did something wrong. Instead of using Sub report parameter expression I was using sub report expression